# Testing for stack unwinding during statement execution

Tags: c#, exception

Is there a way in C# to test whether the execution of a statement happens during exception stack unwinding or not?

Thanks,
Marcello.

Edit:
I mean something like this:

```
using (NewDbTransaction()) { 
  //do some DB stuff here
} <-- here Dispose() of IDisposable is called 

void DbTransactionWrapper.Dispose() { 
  if (InException()) //is this possible???
    Rollback();
  else
    Commit();
}
```

Comment: it's called a try/catch -namely the catch part

Comment: Maybe he means if there is some function you can call to find out if the code is called from within a catch/finally block.

Comment: This can hardly be called regularly used functionality. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Simply catch and rethrow the exception.

Edit: Or did you mean *"how do I detect an exception in the finally block"*? In that case You could just set a flag in the catch block and read it in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

The [stacktrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class may give you some help here, but you'd have to do a fair bit of work yourself examining the stack. I don't think there's an easy way to spot that the code is called from an exception block.